# how to filter out object from array

Tags: reactjs, react-native

sorry to ask simple question, since i'am still new with programming. bellow the data that i get from the Api, and i store it to the state.data[]. the problem is i don't know how to sort data to display only object if cooUUID is equal to "aaaa" and get coopName data from that.

```
Data": [
        {
            "coopUUID": "aaaaaa",
            "coopName": "Koperasi Energi Terbarukan Indonesia (KOPETINDO)",

        },
        {
            "coopUUID": "bbbbb",
            "coopName": "Induk Koperasi Pegawai Republik Indonesia (IKP-RI)",

        },
        {
            "coopUUID": "cccccc",
            "coopName": "KOPERASI STEBANK",
        }
```

```
  constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            data: [],
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
let filter = data.filter(item => item.coopUUID === "aaaa").map(item => item.coopName);
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score -1):

you should try this one

```
var found = Data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.coopUUID== aaaaaa
  })
```